# inherit attributes of one collection in other in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on nodejs and using mongodb.There are two collections which have exact same attributes. I dont want code repetion so i want to inherit attributes of one collection in other. This will also help in the situation when i am changing schema of my one collection and other collection's schema will get changed itself. Given below is the sample schema of one collection.

```
   var projectModel = function () {

    var collection = mongoose.Schema({   
                     A: String,
                     B: String,               
                     C: Number,
                     D: String

            });

           return mongoose.model('projectList', collection);

   };

   module.exports = new projectModel();
```

I want another collection with same attributes. How can i do that? Do i need to use prototype? if yes then how?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with using the same schema twice? Do not put schema definition into the function where you also defined a model based on it, define it separately and use with two models/collections

Answer (score 0):

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({   
    A: String,
    B: String,               
    C: Number,
    D: String
});
exports.Model1 = mongoose.model('Model1', schema, "collection1");
exports.Model2 = mongoose.model('Model2', schema, "collection2");
```